# how to use or_where and where in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, activerecord

I am facing a problem when using active record or_where
how i do or only for one particular field i.e meeting_status

```
$this->db->_protect_identifiers=false;
        $this->db->select("g.category_id,f.doc_type_id,g.category_name,f.doc_type_name,c.meeting_name_id, c.meeting_name as mn, d.meeting_type_id, d.meeting_type_name, e.venue_id, e.venue_name, u.*, (select count(*) from tbl_meeting_decisions where meeting_id=u.meeting_id and record_status= 'ACTIVE') as `meeting_decision`, (select count(*) from tbl_meeting_actions  where meeting_id=u.meeting_id and record_status= 'ACTIVE') as `meeting_action`, (select count(*) from tbl_meeting_actions  where meeting_id=u.meeting_id and action_status='OPEN' and record_status= 'ACTIVE') as `meeting_close_action`");
        $this->db->from('tbl_meeting_plans u');
        $this->db->join('tbl_meeting_names c', 'c.meeting_name_id = u.meeting_name');
        $this->db->join('tbl_meeting_types d', 'd.meeting_type_id = u.meeting_mode_id');
        $this->db->join('tbl_meeting_venue e', 'e.venue_id = u.venue_id ');
        $this->db->join('tbl_document_types f', 'f.doc_type_id = u.meeting_type_id ');
        $this->db->join('tbl_categories g', 'g.category_id = u.meeting_category_id ');

             $this->db->where(array('u.meeting_type_id'=>$str2,'u.meeting_category_id'=>$str1,'u.meeting_status'=>'Planning','u.record_status'=>'ACTIVE'  ));
$this->db->or_where(array('u.meesting_status'=>'Meeting Updated' ));
```

Comment: I am not 100% right, but when there is such situation to apply where clause i always use custom my sql query. 
  $sql = 'YOUR SQL QUERY'
  $query = $this->db->query($sql);
  $res = $query->result_array();
  return $res;

Because i am also facing a lot of problem while using where and or_where clasue in codeIgniter. :(

Comment: why don't you look at the generated query using: `echo $this->db->last_query();` and let us see the query

Comment: @Rajnish Problem was i had to stick with active records or i do the same to.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
 $where = "(u.meeting_status='Planning' or u.meeting_status='Meeting
 Updated') "; 
 $this->db->where($where);
```

Before this use the normal where clause